# What Win7pro application is trying to access IP 166.205.50.104

Tags: windows-7

I discovered a year ago (via my router) that IP 166.205.50.104 was being linked to by my laptop.  I blocked this in my router a year ago.  Yet, my router reveals that my laptop is still attempting to link to that IP address.  How can I figure out which PROGRAM running on my laptop is attempting this link?  The attempts are multiple times daily but at random times. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: ip translates to  mobile-166-205-050-104.mycingular.net - do you have a mobile phone app?

Comment: @SeanCheshire - It could also be a mobile phone :-)

Comment: Good point. Make sure you check the mac address of the machine sending the request in the router.

Answer (score 4):

In a command prompt type:

```
netstat -a -o
```

Find the line with the foreign address that you are interested in. Then open task manager and find the process with the PID that matches the PID in that line.

Haven't messed with netstat in a while. If you do:

```
netstat -b
```

It will tell you the name of the process.

Even better, open a Powershell prompt and do this:

```
netstat -b | Select-String '166.205.50.104' -context 1
```